# webdav sardine jar with JavaEE web application

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, sardine

We have an existing JavaEE web application. We need to connect to a document repository via webdav. I am trying to use sardine but the couldn't find clear setup instructions. Is the Maven build mandatory? Or, is it possible to simply include `sardine.jar` in our application and use the below code?

```
Sardine sardine = SardineFactory.begin("username", "password");
List<DavResource> resources = sardine.list("http://myhost.com/modeshape-webdav/sample/default");
for (DavResource res : resources)
{
  System.out.println(res);
}
```

Comment: Maven will bring you all needed dependencies, because the Sardine library can depend on other libs, and they can depend on another libs, and so on. But you can choose to solve this dependencies on you own, and in such case you don't need Maven.

Comment: thanks, I added sardine library and had to resolve multiple jar dependency issues

Answer (score 0):

If you use Maven, you can add this dependency in your pom.xml to use Sardine :

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.github.lookfirst</groupId>
  <artifactId>sardine</artifactId>
  <version>5.5</version>
</dependency>
```